# Quiz game in tkinter- Cannot get answers to display in window

Tags: python, tkinter

I started learning to code a while but have since been distracted, I spent the last couple of days trying to sort these problems but cannot. I was trying to make a little quiz in tkinter in which a question is displayed, you can type in an answer and the answer is displayed.

Main issues I cannot solve:

1. answers from result.get are not being saved to player_info
2. player_answer_label is not displaying in the main window
3. when it runs out of question in the list it says inde error. I need it to break after this and display some kind of 'end game'
4. Window size is all over the place

```
    try:
        import tkinter
    except ImportError:  # python 2
        import Tkinter as tkinter
    
    import time
    import os
    
    mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
    mainWindow.title = "Radiants"
    mainWindow.geometry = "640x480"
    
    # Questions
    
    question_list = ["I am the remnants of Honour, What is your name?", "What is your age?",
                     "Choose a race you would like to know more about",
                     #"Would you like to know about another race?: ",
                     "What race are you?: ",
                     "Choose an order you would like to know more about: ",
                     #"Would you like to know about another order?: ",
                     "What order are you?: ", ]
    
    # For player data i.e name, age etc
    
    
    
    # Function to bring up next question in question_list into my_label
    
    player_info = []
    
    
    def counter():
        global question_list
        global player_info
        question = question_list.pop(0)
    
        player_info = input.get
    
        for i in question_list:
            Question_label.config(text=question)
            if question not in question_list:
                break
    
        Question_label.config(text=question)
    
    
    
    
    
        print(player_info)
        player_answer_label = player_info
    
    # Function to destroy start button
    #def destroy_start():
    # start.destroy()
    
    # Widgets
    
    
    
    canvas1 = tkinter.Canvas(mainWindow, width=640, height=480)
    canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
    
    frame1 = tkinter.Frame(canvas1, relief="sunken", borderwidth=1, )
    frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='EW')
    
    frame2 = tkinter.Frame(frame1, relief="sunken", borderwidth=1, )
    frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='EW')
    
    # Displays the question
    Question_label = tkinter.Label(frame2, background="White")
    Question_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    
    # input box for answers
    input = tkinter.Entry(frame2)
    input.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='sw')
    
    # Display player answers
    player_answer_label = tkinter.Label(frame2, background="White")
    Question_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
    
    #start = tkinter.Button(frame1, text="Start", command=destroy_start)
    #start.grid(row=2, column=0)
    
    enter_button = tkinter.Button(frame2, text="Enter", command=counter)
    enter_button.grid(row=3, column=0)
    
    
    player_answer_label.config(text=player_info)
    print(player_info)
    
    
    # Start the GUI
    mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

in python you first need to define variables functions and buttons... and then you can use it in buttons, commands etc.
here is repaired code:

```py
try:
    import tkinter
except ImportError:  # python 2
    import Tkinter as tkinter

import time
import os

mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
mainWindow.title = "Radiants"
mainWindow.geometry = "640x480"

# Questions

question_list = ["I am the remnants of Honour, What is your name?", "What is your age?",
                 "Choose a race you would like to know more about",
                 #"Would you like to know about another race?: ",
                 "What race are you?: ",
                 "Choose an order you would like to know more about: ",
                 #"Would you like to know about another order?: ",
                 "What order are you?: ", ]

# For player data i.e name, age etc



# Function to bring up next question in question_list into my_label

player_info = []

def counter():
    global question_list
    global player_info
    question = question_list.pop(0)
    # error!
    player_info = input.get()

    for i in question_list:
        Question_label.config(text=question)
        if question not in question_list:
            break

    Question_label.config(text=question)





    print(player_info)
    player_answer_label = player_info


    
canvas1 = tkinter.Canvas(mainWindow, width=640, height=480)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")

frame1 = tkinter.Frame(canvas1, relief="sunken", borderwidth=1, )
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='EW')

frame2 = tkinter.Frame(frame1, relief="sunken", borderwidth=1, )
frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='EW')

# Displays the question
Question_label = tkinter.Label(frame2, background="White")
Question_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

# input box for answers
input = tkinter.Entry(frame2)
input.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='sw')

# Display player answers
player_answer_label = tkinter.Label(frame2, background="White")
Question_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

#start = tkinter.Button(frame1, text="Start", command=destroy_start)
#start.grid(row=2, column=0)

enter_button = tkinter.Button(frame2, text="Enter", command=counter())
enter_button.grid(row=3, column=0)


player_answer_label.config(text=player_info)
print(player_info)


# Function to destroy start button
#def destroy_start():
# start.destroy()

# Widgets






# Start the GUI
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

I'm hope I'm is help you :)

tested in python 3

Comment: When answering on Stackoverflow, please don't post links to the code. Post the actual code inside the answer. I edited your answer so it includes your code. Also your statement "*if you don't understand only download this*", if OP doesn't understand the answer then you haven't actually helped them.

Comment: Also a fun fact that I just learned: if you name your script to `copy.py`, you can't open it with IDLE 3.9. That is because IDLE uses `import code` and it doesn't import the real `code` library.

Comment: thx for posting code, this is my first time when I answering next time I'm will answer with explanation and how to post code?

Comment: Look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).